# Interpret Javascript web application using Python

Tags: javascript, python

Excuse me if my coding lingo is off, I'm familiar with coding but still what you might consider a beginner. Let me first explain why I'm doing this, followed by what I what I want from it to hopefully give you an idea of how to tackle this problem.

I'm a small streamer on dlive, to reward my viewers for watching I'm using a service called Incent, that rewards viewers with crypto for picking up dropcodes. I've noticed that people have a better experience when someone has typed out the code in the chat rather than it blinking on screen for 30 seconds only to disappear. It's not always someone sits in chat and types it out and sometimes there are spelling errors etc. I figured I wanted to automate  the process to make the integration of incent into my stream more seamless. I've coded my own chat bot using python and just wanted to push the code through that.The bot is working and able to send messages, so that's not my issue here.

Now the issue I have is how do I make python interpret what's happening on the drop url, making it take just the drop code. The incent drop url uses javascript so I'm not entirely sure how to make it work. Here's a url to the preview, so you can get an idea what happens when a drop comes https://get.incent.com/overlays/v1/dropcodes/28mIAiGQNa7adlZAg6948N:15LCP76AiNGk6RmRAaKKep?preview

I'm not sure what route to go from here. I was playing around the idea with web scraping, but I'd rather it run in the background and not having to open up, say a selenium browser every time it needs to check for the code. A method like that I imagine would have to run continuously inside a while loop. Ideally I'd want python to just receive the code every time it drops. I thought I could use requests to accomplish this, but I have to admit that I don't know how to make that work.

Hopefully you now have an idea of what the problem is and I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

- Open the page via headless browser
- wait until the code arrives (an element with `class^="RewardCodestyles__Code"]` - meaning that starts with that class)
- evaluate the `innertText` or `textContent` of that element to retrieve the code
- sleep for some time (10 sec in this example) and start over

Sample code (with [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/)):

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

URL = 'https://get.incent.com/overlays/v1/dropcodes/28mIAiGQNa7adlZAg6948N:15LCP76AiNGk6RmRAaKKep?preview'


async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL)

    # wait until the code arrives
    await page.waitForFunction('''() => {
        return !!document.body.querySelector('[class^="RewardCodestyles__Code"]')
    }
    ''', {
        'timeout': 60000
    })

    # then just extract the code
    code = await page.evaluate('''() => {
        return document.body.querySelector('[class^="RewardCodestyles__Code"]').innerText
    }''')

    # do things with the code here
    print(code)

    await browser.close()


async def forever():
    while True:
        await main()
        # sleep a bit here - for 10 secs.
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(forever())
```

An output from a sample run:

```
TEST-C0D3
TEST-C0D3
TEST-C0D3
TEST-C0D3
TEST-C0D3
TEST-C0D3
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'll need some time to digest all of this information, I am new after all.

Comment: Ok, so I have spent a lot of time yesterday and some time today to figure out what async and pyppeteer is. Async is to have multiple functions run alongside each other, right? The pyppeteer is the headless browser adaptation from Javascript used to identefy the objects on the page. Since I'm already using a while loop to continuously "listen" to the chat, I'm guessing I need to make that into an async function as well? And should I put this function into the async forever function?